# User registration in Grails

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails

I've installed Spring Security Core and Spring Security UI plugins in my project with hope to get something like this:  [**User Management**](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/guide/user.html).

But on every action I get the first picture on this link (Member sign in) and I can't do anything else (Register as new user or Log in...).

I'm new in this so if anybody can explain me what to do and how to set it to work properly...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably because that you have wrong order in your static URL rules or all of the rules are defined for IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY users. Check your config.groovy and see if there exists any rules for anonymous users or IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED . If you have rules including IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY then you should change them. See this [blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/) for details.

Comment: I didn't add anything in config.groovy.

Comment: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'aplikacija.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'aplikacija.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className='aplikacija.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules=[
 '/':                              ['permitAll'],
 '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
 '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
 '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
 '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
This is added by spring security